# Convert tidy dataframe to dataframe with list of lists

Tags: r

Here is a tidy dataframe

```
df_tidy <- tibble(
  company = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  line_data = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
)
```

The format required is:

`df_ll <- structure(list(company = c("A", "B"), line_data = list(list(c(1, 2, 1)), list(c(2, 2, 1)))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

How do I transform df_tidy into df_ll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouped by 'company' `summarise` the 'line_data' in a `list`

```
df_ll2 <- df_tidy %>%
    group_by(company) %>%
    summarise(line_data = list(list(line_data)))
```

-checking with expected

```
all.equal(df_ll, df_ll2)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `nest` or `nest_by` and then convert the `tibble` to a `list`

```
df_tidy %>% 
   nest_by(company, .key = "line_data") %>% 
   mutate(line_data = list(list(unlist(line_data)))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `plyr` package:

```
df_ll <- dlply(df_tidy,.(company),c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create a tibble comprised of: df_ll2 => tibble
df_ll2 <- tibble(
  # Uniquify the company vector: company => character vector
  company = unique(df_tidy$company),
  # Split the data into a list by the company vector, coerce each
  # element to an unnamed list:
  line_data = unname(
    lapply(
      with(df_tidy, split(line_data, company)), 
      list
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.